# How to stop jumping again when character is in air (double jump)?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm using touch inputs in my game to control the character. I would like to know how to disable my character from jumping again in the air.

```
if (FingerTouchy.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
       charcter.transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
       float jumpForce = 250;
                        charcter.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));

                    }
```

**Update**

Im using [Collision Detection](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/on-collision-enter)

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            grounded = true;

        }
    }
```

And checking if charcter is grounded

```
if(FingerTouchy.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {

                    float jumpForce=250;
                    if (grounded)
                        continue;
                    charcter.transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
                    charcter.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0,jumpForce));
                        grounded=false;

                }
```

using collision/collision2d doesn't work too.

Answer (score 3):

I've handling ground status with raycast.

I declare a global grounded variable and use it to check if my character can jump.

In the fixed update of my character controller, i call my groundedUpdater().

```
void GroundedUpdater ()
{
    grounded = false; //Set to false every frame by default
    RaycastHit2D[] hit;
    hit = Physics2D.RaycastAll (transform.position, Vector2.down, 0.6f);
    // you can increase RaycastLength and adjust direction for your case
    foreach (var hited  in hit) {
        if (hited.collider.gameObject == gameObject) //Ignore my character
            continue;
        // Don't forget to add tag to your ground
        if (hited.collider.gameObject.tag == "Ground") { //Change it to match ground tag
            grounded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And where i handle inputs i do this

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        if (grounded) { // can jump
            rig.AddForce (Vector3.up * jumpPower, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            grounded = false; //Avoid direct double jump
        }
    }
```

Comment: While the code presented here is the one that I feel best suits the asker, there are some minor changes we can make for better efficiency.  We can drop the `if(hited.collider.gameobject = gameobject)` statement entirely if we assign a layer mask to our ground objects that is used only for things we can stand on, and then raycast against only that layer.

Comment: @Draco18s did it work for you?

Comment: @user75648 eh? I didn't pull any of these answers into Unity myself, I was just reading them.  I happen to use the Standard Assets character controller which handles this on its own (also, I work in 3D, not 2D, so I do not know if a similar standard asset exists).

Comment: grounded bool is returning false

Comment: @user75648 try to increase raycast length or change raycast vector angle in my case it's for 2D platform game. You can use ondrawgizmos to debug the raycast

Answer (score 0):

To do that, make a script name `Ground`. Attach `Rigidbody2D` to Ground and mark it as `Kinematic`. Assuming that your `character` has `"Player"` tag. Now time to use some `delegate` stuff.

A simple definition of `delegate` that `delegate` is use to notify other `class` on an event, even if that other `class` don't have any instance of first `class`. In other words, `delegate` does broadcast a message, then all other classes whichever wants to receive that broadcast, just set a listener in it.

For example, `class A` has an specific event. `class B` and `class C` wants to get notify when that specific even occurs in `class A` without having an instance of `class A`.

So similarly you can use `delegate` keeping a good structure of code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ground : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void OnCharacterLandedDelegate();
    public static event OnCharacterLandedDelegate OnCharacterLandedListener;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            if (OnCharacterLandedListener != null)
                OnCharacterLandedListener();
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the script where you are handling touch. Add these lines of code.

```
bool _shouldJump = true;
void OnEnable()
{
    Ground.OnCharacterLandedListener += EnableJump;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    Ground.OnCharacterLandedListener -= EnableJump;
}

void EnableJump()
{
    _shouldJump = true;
}
```

Somewhere in your code,

```
if(FingerTouchy.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
{
    //charcter.transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    Jump();
}

void Jump()
{
    if (!_shouldJump)
        return;
    _shouldJump = false;
    float jumpForce=250;
    charcter.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0,jumpForce));
}
```

Comment: Made some edit, have a look

Comment: Using delegates seems like overkill to me in this situation, since you call it with a single if-check in `Update`. you could just call `EnableJump` directly, or even you could just do `_shouldJump = true;`

Comment: Update is my last resort

Comment: In a more complex code, this structure would definetely be the first choice of me; but for short scripts, I try to keep code as simple as possible to not to get confused while reading it later. But it is a matter of preferance, actually.

Comment: Actually even in this scenario how you can achieve 100% accuracy using Update? You will get glitch somehow. Second thing I avoid using update as much as possible

Comment: here it is, not using update but truncated delegates and events: http://pastebin.ca/3291627

Comment: You did it. I appreciate. But don't you think that this code disturbs architecture? As you have to get character in `Ground` script? Which is attached on **Ground**?

Comment: But you gave me an idea, actually I prefer using delegates. Well, for easiness let me update the answer according to your logic

Comment: No no, that will not work what I thought. Sorry. Other than delegates, you have to disturb a normal architecture of code and carry character to the ground only to truncate delegates.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the game object's velocity in y axis.

```
if (FingerTouchy.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && charcter.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y==0)
                {
       charcter.transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
       float jumpForce = 250;
    charcter.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));

                    }
```

This just works fine.

Let me know if this has any drawbacks.

Comment: This will not work 100% accurate, as if ground has some bumpiness, or even not, moving rigidbody having Y velocity exactly zero is difficult any how. Second thing, during jump and falling of character, at one point Y velocity would must pass through **0**, which is a glitch. This speech is only for information sharing. Hope you understand, at least little bit. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (FingerTouchy.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        float jumpForce = 250;
        if (playerIsGrounded)
            charcter.transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            charcter.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));

    }
```

**In the grounded check code :**

```
void OnTriggerEnter(coll Collider)
{
    if (coll.tag == "Ground")
        playerIsGrounded = true;
}

void OnTriggerLeave(coll Collider)
{
    if(coll.tag == "Ground")
        playerIsGrounded = false;
}
```

---

Haven't used unity in a while but I think it's something like this?

Comment: @user75648 When the `OnTriggerEnter(coll Collider)` is called it will set the variable to true (since the player is on the ground) and the force (jump) is only called when this variable is set to true. And since its set to false when the player stops colliding with the ground, the player won't jump when he is in the air.

Comment: on checking playerIsGrounded=true , I'm still able to jump more than once and on playerIsGrounded=false , the AddForce line is ignored.

Comment: @user75648 I edited the answer, maybe this will work?

Comment: playerIsGrounded is now returning false and I'm still able to jump more than once.

Comment: @user75648 The transform and addForce lines should be ignored when the player is in the air, unless I'm being really dumb. Is it still running those 2 lines when you are not touching the ground?

Comment: playerIsGrounded returns false and yes it still running those 2 lines

Comment: @user75648 ohh it returns faalse, sorry. Uh, change if(isPlayerGrounded) to if(!isPlayerGrounded) should work. I think at least.

Comment: This method won't work well in general. Imagine you walk from one platform onto another adjacent one. At first, your trigger touches the left platform, and `playerIsGrounded` is set to true, Then your trigger touches the right platform, and `playerIsGrounded`... is already true, so nothing changes. Lastly, your trigger exits the left platform, which sets `playerIsGrounded` to false - even though you're still touching the right platform! Instead you want a `playerGroundContactsCount` integer that you increment/decrement. Also, use `CompareTag` not `==` with tags.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use the Boolean variable. Make it true if the character on the ground else make it false. If it is true then only add the force to the character.

Ex:

First check the player is on the ground.

This code snippet goes on ground 
GameObject.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            if (OnCharacterLandedListener != null)
                OnCharacterLandedListener();
               new PlayerScript().canJump=true;// if player on the ground
        }
    }
```

Your input action

This code snippet goes to the Player gameobject.

```
   [HideInspector]   //Don't show  this field in the inspector.
    public bool canJump=false;  

        if(FingerTouchy.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            //charcter.transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            if(canJump)
                Jump();
        }

        void Jump()
        {
            if (!_shouldJump)
                return;
             _shouldJump = false;
             float jumpForce=250;
             charcter.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0,jumpForce));
             canJump=false; // if not on the ground
        }
```

Comment: Please understand the needs, code given by asker and then give your input. Your answer completely confuse the person who asked. He is a beginner. According to your answer, you are enabling in `OnCollisionEnter` which is attached to the ground, and with the delegate call and accessing that flag in another script that is controlling the character. MAN!!! Gimme a break. You are creating flag here and accessing it there and even didn't understand the implemented functionality. Well, this speech is just for information sharing, nothing personal., hope you understand.

Comment: @HamzaHasan Sorry for that mistake. I hope now it's alright

Comment: Again, you are creating new instance of `PlayerScript` having no relation with the one attached to Player `GameObject` :)

Answer (score -2):

Since I mis understood, I would use a part of @HamzaHasan 's answer, but I would not use AddForce.

I advice to not use Addforce to let a character jump/move because this is not ment for character movement, this is more or less used for explosion that give a "force" to your body, or space ships floating movement.
I would advice using `transform.Translate(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);`.
Where vector.3 defines the direction this could be;

- `Vector3.left`
- `Vector3.right`
- `Vector3.up`
- `Vector3.down`

Comment: The asker wants to prevent *double jumping.*  That is, if the character has already jumped (or is falling) he doesn't want to let the player jump again.

Comment: Ah, I misread there, i read "How do I prevent my player from jumping in the air". OP could have written "how to prevent player from double jump"

Comment: @JpHouten why would i use Vector3?

Comment: @user75648 you can also use Vector2, it depends on your game, if you have a 2D game you should use Vector2.